# MFC Formatting Dates with Locale

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2005, winapi

I have to print out a date in "extendend mode", like this:

```
Thursday 02 August 2013
```

Using COleDateTime I have no problems, but I need to print this stuff in local language, in my case Italian. I've found this code in an old compiler that use base SDK commands:

```
char                            lpDateStr[128], lpTimeStr[128];
SYSTEMTIME                      today;
WString                         str;

FileTimeToSystemTime( &IdUnicoK1, &today );
GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, &today, NULL, lpDateStr, sizeof(lpDateStr) );
GetTimeFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT, &today, NULL, lpTimeStr, sizeof(lpTimeStr) );
str.Sprintf( "%s,  %s", lpDateStr, lpTimeStr );
```

that in MFC, according to the MSDN is:

```
SYSTEMTIME stBuf;
CString    strD;
CString    strT;
CString    strData;

FileTimeToSystemTime( &m_pK1->m_ftMyData, &stBuf );
strD = _T("dddd dd MMMM yyyy");
GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, &stBuf, NULL, strD.GetBuffer(), strD.GetLength() );
strT = _T("HH':'mm':'ss");
GetTimeFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT, &stBuf, NULL, strT.GetBuffer(), strT.GetLength() );
strData.Format( _T("%s, %s"), strD, strT );
```

but this lead me to the following result:

```
dddd dd MMMM yyyy, HH':'mm':'ss
```

Where I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MFC version is not functionally equivalent to the "straight C" version.

You can use the first version and convert the result to a CString, like:

```
CString strDateTime;
strDateTime.Format("%s,  %s", lpDateStr, lpTimeStr);
```

Otherwise, you will need to do something like:

```
FileTimeToSystemTime( &m_pK1->m_ftMyData, &stBuf );
GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, &stBuf, NULL, strD.GetBuffer(128), 128);
GetTimeFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, TIME_FORCE24HOURFORMAT, &stBuf, NULL, strT.GetBuffer(128), 128);
strD.ReleseBuffer();
strT.ReleseBuffer();
strData.Format(_T("%s, %s"), strD, strT);
```

Comment: I accepted this question because in my opinion, which can be silly, is more MFC-like, but both are correct and acceptable.

Comment: @IssamTP: fair enough - I assume that my solution works as well, correct? (I was writing a test program to see what was wrong with it...)

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling `ReleaseBuffer()`, nor initializing the `strD` and `strM` to something long enough to hold the result - so both calls to `GetDateFormat()` fail.

It is better to use static buffers:

```
TCHAR pszDate[200];
GetDateFormat( LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, &stBuf, NULL, pszDate, 200 );
```